# How to fix "DLL load failed while importing win32api" While running jupyter notebook in anaconda command Prompt

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Steps to by which error occur:

Step 1: activate pyfinance

Step 2: jupyter notebook

after that Bellow error occur

win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)

```
  File "c:\users\pankaj\anaconda2\envs\pyfinance\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 361, in win32_restrict_file_to_user

    import win32api

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified module could not be found.[W 18:19:50.919 NotebookApp] Unhandled error[E 18:19:50.922 NotebookApp] {

  "Host": "localhost:8888",

  "Connection": "keep-alive",

  "Content-Length": "91",

  "Origin": "http://localhost:8888",

  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36",

  "Content-Type": "application/json",

  "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",

  "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",

  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",

  "X-Xsrftoken": "2|4f30d23f|2d79010e980e1f99af7ddf7d0a8cd57b|1585979791",
  "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
  "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=python3",
  "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
  "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|4f30d23f|2d79010e980e1f99af7ddf7d0a8cd57b|1585979791; ext_name=ojplmecpdpgccookcobabopnaifgidhf; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1586004538|23:username-localhost-8888|44:OTA2MWZlNDhhMTYwNDFjMGI2ZjFiMWZhYWE1Zjk5MWI=|ce85d5a60cfed037ccae39c67895568efe270ec339c1e5a273281c9ea8336167\""
}
```